# Error while using PHP to run R scripts using a sequence or vector as parameter

Tags: php, r

I am working on a small project which uses graphs generated by R scripts, which get their values from a PHP script.
But I have problems using vectors as parameters.

From PHP I use simply

```
echo shell_exec("plot.roc.curves.R ".$d." ".$sigma." \"".$distribution."\"  \"".$f."\"  \"".$x."\"  \"".$y."\" ".$size);
```

This is my R script

```
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)            # allow command line arguments

d            <- as.integer(args[1])
sigma        <- as.integer(args[2])  # sigma
distribution <- args[3]              # distribution (cauchy, norm, exp, binom, ... )
f            <- args[4]              # the filename of the output file
xaxis        <- args[5]              # the text for the x axis
yaxis        <- args[6]              # the text for the y axis
size         <- as.integer(args[7])  # the size of the generated png file (x and y)

plot.roc.curves <- function(d_f,sigma_f,distribution_f,xaxis_f,yaxis_f)
{
cdf <- get(paste("p",distribution_f,sep="")) # connects p (for distribution) to the given distribution
                                             # and generates a function cdf() (e.g. pcauchy()->cdf()
qf <- get(paste("q",distribution_f,sep=""))  # connects q (for quantile) to the given distribution
                                             # and generates a function qf() (e.g. qnorm()->qf()
di <- d_f[1]                                 # set di to the first element of the list d

roc.curve.d <- function(x)
    {
    return(1-cdf((qf(1-x)-di)/(sigma_f)))   # the main formula
    }
gcolours <- c(1)                            # set gcolours to list element 1
curve(roc.curve.d,from=0,to=1,ylim=c(0,1),lwd=3,xlab=xaxis_f, ylab=yaxis_f)
# draw a line with the function roc.curve.d from x=0 to 1 and y=0 to 1 with thickness 3

curve(1*x,add=T,lty=2)                      # draw a diagonal line

for (i in 2:length(d_f))
    {
    gcolours <- c(gcolours,((i-1)%%8)+1)    # makes sure, that gcolours is always 1:8
    di <- d_f[i]                            # set di to the value of index i
    curve(roc.curve.d,lwd=3,col=gcolours[i],add=TRUE)   #
    }

legend("bottomright",pch=15,legend=d_f,col=gcolours,title="d")  # draws a legend in the bottom right corner
}


png(filename = f, width = size, height = size)   # generate the empty png-file like a paper sheet
plot.roc.curves(d,sigma,distribution,xaxis,yaxis) # write the curve on the new generated sheet
dev.off()                                        # close the graphic file
```

Now heres the problem:

This R script workes fine with e.g.

```
plot.roc.curves.R 1 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

but I need to use sequences or lists for the first parameter, e.g.

```
plot.roc.curves.R 1:5 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

or

```
plot.roc.curves.R 1,2,3,5 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

which produces NA error while running from the command line and leads to an only partially correct image without the colored curves after the diagonal line.
I removed the as.integer from "as.integer(args[1])" and thought of annother way.
I  tried

```
plot.roc.curves.R "1:5" 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

and

```
plot.roc.curves.R "1,2,3,5" 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

but that does not work either as this is treatened as string and not as sequence. After some hours of probing I have found a solution for my problem - but I am sure this is not the right solution although it works. I inserted after the beginning of the function plot.roc.curves directly after the curled brace:

```
if(regexpr(":", d_f)>0)          # if d_f contains at least one colon (therefore it's an integer sequence)
    {
    d_f <- unlist(lapply(as.list(d_f), function(x) eval(parse(text=x)))) # convert string into a integer sequence
    }
else if(regexpr(",", d_f)>0)     # if d_f contains at least one comma (therefore it's a list of numeric values)
    {
    d_f <- as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(d_f,",")))                         # convert string into numeric
    }
else
    {
    d_f <- as.numeric(d_f)       # assume parameter is numeric and integer
    }
```

I know, this is ugly. But each time I need to use some other types I have to write a new converting sequence. That can't be right.

Actually I need to give a vector to the script:

```
plot.roc.curves.R c(1,2,3) 2 "norm" "file" "x" "y" 500
```

There must be a simple way - but I haven't found it.
Can anyone help me to understand how to send mixed types (e.g. vectors or sequences) from the command line or from PHP to a R script ? 
Any help would be highly appreciated.